# HttpParams refuse to set

Tags: javascript, angular

Using Angular 8 I'm trying to set an [HttpParam](https://v8.angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams) using the code below, see the result on the last line.

```
let newParams = new HttpParams();
newParams.set('ordering', 'name');
console.log('getting: ', newParams.get('ordering'));
// getting: null
```

Using the code below i see that the param has been set as i expected:

```
let newParams = new HttpParams().set('ordering', 'name');
console.log('getting: ', newParams.get('ordering'));
// getting: name
```

looking at the docs i cant understand why this isn't working.  Is this a bug, or am I just missing something fundamental in javascript?

Comment: set(key, value) method of HttpParams interface returns a new instance of HttpParams containing the new entry of key-value pair. Refer the official docs for more information (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpParams#set).

Comment: Thanks, i see now that the entire description is dedicated to this... woops... would be good to have an example in the docs though, that would have saved me some time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set` returns a new instance. That is effectively being thrown away in your first example.

A long-hand version to demonstrate the problem might be

```
let newParams = new HttpParams();
let discardedParams = newParams.set('ordering', 'name');
console.log('getting: ', newParams.get('ordering'));
```

From the docs:

> set()
>
> Returns
>
> HttpParams: A new body with the new value.